# SharePoint application server down

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-on-prem

My SharePoint application server was crashed, but my SharePoint database server is up and running.

How can I install only application server and point it to my database server?

I am using SharePoint 2013 environment.

Answer (score 3):

Do the following.

- Build a new SharePoint server, with same version / build number. (same CU level)
- Run the config wizard and join the server to existing farm.
- Now start all the services on this server which are running on old one.
- If there is any custom settings, please do that.

Answer (score 0):

Building a fresh server from scratch!

## Some instructions to clone your server:

In source server/farm,

Take a full backup from your current farm.

Take a full backup of SharePoint content databases in case you want to use
Database-Attach method.

Backup all the deployed SharePoint solutions (WSP) in your farm if exist.

Determine the SQL version.

Determine the build number and the latest CU installed on your source farm be installed on your destination farm.

[It might help you take a look](https://meritsolutions.com/cloning-sharepoint-2013-environment/)